# what are my options for linking directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, filesystems, php-fpm

I have a configuration file which refers to a file structure. This is what I have

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://XXXX.co.uk/public_html/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://XXXX.co.uk//public_html/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://XXXX.co.uk//public_html/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://XXXX.co.uk//public_html/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://XXXX.co.uk//public_html/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/XXXX/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/XXXX/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'XXXX_com1');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXX');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'XXXX_com1');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');?>
```

Now this works as long as codebase is on one server, however I want to move some of the directories to another server.

```
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/');
    define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/system/database/');
    define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/XXXX/public_html/language/');
```

Both of the servers will be the ubuntu servers. What is the best way to do this. I am kinda lost and not sure how this could be accomplished

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do.  You can't really move arbitrary parts of the codebase to another server.  I mean, you could, but that's silly.  The processing would still be occurring on the primary server.  At best, you'd end up with a barely manageable and completely unscaleable hodgepodge of shares and symlinks.

However, you could encapsulate complete 'features' of the code as separate applications and run those on separate web servers.  e.g. have all user image handling at http://images.XXXX.co.uk/.  This server would handle uploading, storing, recording to the database, and serving of just user-submitted images.

Then you set the HTTP_IMAGE constant to http://images.XXXX.co.uk/whatever/path.  Have upload forms point to that link, write image urls with that link, etc.  In this way, the application is still abstracted from the underlying server - the only interfaces used are HTTP/S and database protocols.

For a more definitive answer, we'll need more specific details.  You won't (or shouldn't) move just any old file to any server, but specific components of your application can be relocated or separated.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use NFS. Share the relevant directories from the remote server and mount them on the local one.